# Onresize function is not working in price filter slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to develop a price filter in my project and i have done this and it is not working

```
    <div class="price_range_caption">

<span class="currency_from">Rs.</span><span id="price_range_fromprice" >1250</span><span id="price_range_toprice">6600</span><span class="currency_to">Rs.</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = create_price_slider(170, 0, 170, 1250, 6600,"price");
window.onresize = function() {


var url = window.location.href;
var pa = document.getElementById("price_range_fromprice").innerHTML;
var pb = document.getElementById("price_range_toprice").innerHTML;

window.location.assign(url+"&price="+pa+"-"+pb);


};


</script>
```

URL is generating good but its not moving on that URL when i resize the price range

Comment: The `onresize` method is only for the window resize event, not the slider move.

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/DuZf0.png i want to develop this and when i change the price range then page get refresh with selected price range

Comment: Show your code then; its clear you're not including all of it, and what you didn't include is highly relevant.

Comment: There is no global function called `create_price_slider`.  Show us the source of that function.

Comment: listen bro i am new in java script here is couple of JS files included i don't know from where this function is being called. if you can help me with your technique i will be very thankful to you. can you help me to build the price filter?

Comment: No, I can't.  SO doesn't exist as a free code service  To write such a function is out of the scope of this site.  jQuery does have a slider pre-built, in its UI module.  I recommend you look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine:

```
window.onresize = function() {

    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");

};
```

So you probably have an error in reading `pa` /`pb`. Check your developer console for errors.

> i resize the price range

I am assuming you meant to say "resize the window" cause that is what you are using in your provided code.

Comment: I'm assuming they meant what they said, only they're applying the wrong method to the event.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DuZf0.png

i want to develop this and when i change the price range then page get refresh with selected price range

Comment: @atifaltaf Then show your code for the slider.  We can't give you a solution if we don't know what we're working with.